# Comprobar fechas en la validación de un formulario

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla Oferta con los siguientes valores:

```
Schema::create('ofertas', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->string('empresa');
        $table->string('sector');
        $table->date('fecha_limite');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Entonces creo un formulario en el cual creo una nueva oferta y tras rellenarlo creo la nueva oferta:

```
public function introducir(Request $request){
        $normas=[
            'titulo'=>'required',
            'descripcion'=>'required',
            'empresa'=>'required',
            'sector'=>'required',
            'fecha_limite'=>'required'
        ];

        $mensajes=[
            'titulo.required'=>'El titulo es obligatorio',
            'descripcion.required'=>'La descripcion es obligatoria',
            'empresa.required'=>'La empresa es obligatoria',
            'sector.required'=>'El sector es obligatorio',
            'fecha_limite.required'=>'La fecha limite es obligatoria'
        ];

        $v=Validator::make($request->all(),$normas,$mensajes);

        if($v->fails())
            return back()->withErrors($v);
        else{
            $oferta=Oferta::create(request()->all());
            return back()->with('message',['success','La oferta de trabajo se ha creado con exito']);
        }
    }
```

Antes de crear el formulario reviso que todas y cada una de las columnas tengan un valor, pero quiero ademas que al recibir la fecha compruebe si es posterior a la fecha actual. ¿Como lo reviso en el diccionario de normas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar la validación `after:date` de Laravel.

Obtenemos la fecha actual:

```
$fechaActual=date('Y-m-d');
```

La variable $normas debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
$normas=[
            'titulo'=>'required',
            'descripcion'=>'required',
            'empresa'=>'required',
            'sector'=>'required',
            'fecha_limite'=>'required|after:'.$fechaActual
        ];
```

Y los mensajes:

```
$mensajes=[
            'titulo.required'=>'El titulo es obligatorio',
            'descripcion.required'=>'La descripcion es obligatoria',
            'empresa.required'=>'La empresa es obligatoria',
            'sector.required'=>'El sector es obligatorio',
            'fecha_limite.required'=>'La fecha limite es obligatoria',
            'fecha_limite. after'=>'La fecha limite tiene que ser superior a la fecha de hoy'
        ];
```

Comment: Gracias, ha funcionado.